# Does it make sense to redirect by calling a separate page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a logout page triggered by a jquery post through a button.

The logout script is simply

```
<?php

session_start();

session_destroy();

header("Location: new location");

?>
```

When navigating to this page by url, it works, session is destroyed, page is redirected. But when calling it by a jquery post

```
<script>
$.post("logout.php");
</script>
```

Nothing happens, it could be that the jquery post request isn't working.

I'm just wondering if there is no point to doing it this way.

Comment: Maybe it's just the redirection that it's not working. If it's ajax you should return a JSON response for example indicating that the session was destroyed and then use window.redirect in JS.

Comment: You should try: `$.post("logout.php", function(){window.location.reload()});` and at least check your console for any error...

Comment: thanks guys. @Keyne, I have yet to use JSON for anything, I want to implement it at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use `$.get` instead of `$.post` as it is much faster.

This is a logout page triggered by a jquery post through a button.

`header("Location: new location");`

will cause the logout.php itself to redirect and only will change the returning reslut and won't redirect the caller page itself.

try like:

```
<script>
$.get('logout.php', function(){ documnt.location.href='/index.php' });
</script>
```

this will redirect to the page you want after ajax is excuted.

Comment: he's expecting a redirection after loading logout.php

Comment: I think I read somewhere/was told not to use GET if sending data, if something is being sent backwards (from target back to origin) should I then not use GET? In this situation I'm just executing what is on the logout script then to trigger a redirect so I can use GET in this case. I think.

Comment: well you are not sending any data here that you don't want to appear in the addressbar. if you were sending data that should not be visible to the users and must not appear in the address bar thats the case

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: new location");`

This PHP code of course redirects when it is loaded as a file. But then, when it comes to

```
<script>
$.post("logout.php");
</script>
```

This is an AJAX request. AJAX Request is the one that just requests a page and responds the HTML contents of the page. Therefore, the `header()` function doesn't redirect the page in which the `<script>` lies.

Instead of `$.post` you might want to use `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax
{
 url: 'logout.php',
 type: 'POST',
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 success: function(){
  window.location='new location';
 }
}
```

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if that is the reason why it wasn't working. I mean, by using AJAX the page isn't refreshed, but in the end you will be refreshing the page anyway when redirecting, so why use ajax? I don't know.

Comment: It's your call to simply link it to PHP file directly or make call to it through AJAX.